# Connecting two coordinates on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, mapping

I have about 500 flight data, where it has been separated as two csv's file (departure and arrival), in which each csv has 500 coordinate (lattitude and longitude).

The data looks like this

|  | time_s | lat_deg | lon_deg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.0 | 30 | -90 |
| 2 | 4.0 | 31 | -84 |
| 3 | 6.0 | 35 | -89 |
| 4 | 8.0 | 35 | 97 |
| 5 | 10.0 | 35 | 49 |
| 6 | 12.0 | 35 | 24 |
| 7 | 14.0 | 35 | 78 |
| 8 | 16.0 | 35 | 49 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 500 | 1000.0 | 22 | 45 |

I want to plot this coordinates on GEE, where each coordinate is shown as point, and then the flight data (for example the first row(1) of departure and arrival is connected as a line.

So far I managed to show the point, as it is looked like this

[image: each point is representing coordinate, either it is departure or arrival coordinate]

Is that possible to connect each flight data (departure and arrival) as a line

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to express the line between two points is as the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the union of the two points — the smallest convex shape containing two points is a line segment.

`point1.union(point2).convexHull()`

(You could also retrieve the `.coordinates()` of the points and assemble them into the coordinates of a LineString. But that would be more code and the performance difference is probably small.)

Putting this together with joining the two tables:

```
var departures = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-112.8, 40.1), {
    id: '001',
  }),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-80.3, 37.0), {
    id: '002',
  }),
]);
var arrivals = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-78.0, 39.8), {
    id: '001',
  }),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-77.6, 38.1), {
    id: '002',
  }),
]);

var lines = ee.Join.inner()
  .apply(departures, arrivals, ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'id', rightField: 'id'}))
  .map(function (joinFeature) {
    var origin = ee.Feature(joinFeature.get('primary'));
    var destination = ee.Feature(joinFeature.get('secondary'));
    var line = origin.geometry().union(destination.geometry()).convexHull();
    return joinFeature.setGeometry(line);
  });

print(lines);
Map.addLayer(lines);
Map.addLayer(departures, {color: 'CC0000'}, 'Departures');
Map.addLayer(arrivals, {color: '0088FF'}, 'Arrivals');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/15d8c71401713bb7106412aec34ac0ba

Note that there needs to be some property in common between the two tables to match them with each other — in my example, the 'id' property I made up. You can't use the order of rows in the CSV files because Earth Engine does not preserve that order when you upload a table.

[image]